# Solr unit testing Moq Solr.Query()

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, solr, moq

I'm trying to Moq Solr's Query() function. I can get the code to compile but when it runs I get the error:

```
Object of type 'SolrNet.SolrQuery' cannot be converted to type 'SolrNet.SolrQueryResults`1[SolrProject.Document']
```

Below is how I mock the Query() function. I don't know why it's trying to convert. SolrQuery is the parameter to the Query() function while SolrQueryResults is the return type.

```
Mock<ISolrOperations<Document>> solr = new Mock<ISolrOperations<Document>>();

solr.Setup(x => x.Query(It.IsAny<SolrQuery>()))
                .Returns<SolrQueryResults<Document>>(s =>
                {
                    SolrQueryResults<Document> data = new SolrQueryResults<Document>();

                    data.Add(new Document
                        {
                            Author = "Bob"
                        });

                    return data;
                });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is very simple actually. The generic argument of the `Returns<T>` method in `Moq` means a type of a parameter exposed by a mocked method but not a return type.

The code below shows you what you want to do. The generic argument should be `SolrQuery`, not `SolrQueryResults<Document>`.

```
solr.Setup(x => x.Query(It.IsAny<SolrQuery>()))
                .Returns<SolrQuery>(s =>
                {
                    SolrQueryResults<Document> data = new SolrQueryResults<Document>();

                    data.Add(new Document
                        {
                            Author = "Bob"
                        });

                    return data;
                });
```